# Connection refused: localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9000 with gRPC

Tags: java

I creating a gRPC server but everything seems to run okay but the server never starts up on the specifies port and application is throwing no errors. But when I test with telnet on that specific port,  I get this from terminal

```
isaack$ telnet localhost 9000
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

Below is my code to create the server (NB: All the services are generated okay with proto and the generated code has no errors)

```
import java.io.File;

import io.grpc.Server;
import io.grpc.ServerBuilder;
import io.grpc.ServerInterceptors;
import io.grpc.ServerServiceDefinition;

public class EmployeeServiceServer {

    private Server server;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            EmployeeServiceServer service = new EmployeeServiceServer();
            service.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }

    private void start() throws InterruptedException {
        File certificate = new File("/Users/i/certificates/cert.pem");
        File key = new File("/Users/i/certificates/key.pem");
        final int port = 9000;
        EmployeeService employeeService = new EmployeeService();
        ServerServiceDefinition serverServiceDefinition = ServerInterceptors.interceptForward(employeeService,
                new HeaderServerInterceptor());
        server = ServerBuilder.forPort(port).useTransportSecurity(certificate, key).addService(serverServiceDefinition)
                .build();

        System.out.println("Listening on Port " + port);
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Shuttin Down Server");
                EmployeeServiceServer.this.stop();
            }

        });

        server.awaitTermination();

    }

    private void stop() {
        if (server != null) {
            server.isShutdown();
        }
    }

}
```

Below is the log from but when I ping it, I get nothing.

```
Listening on Port 9000
```

My client is throwing this error as well:

```
Exception in thread "main" io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.toStatusRuntimeException(ClientCalls.java:233)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.getUnchecked(ClientCalls.java:214)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:139)
    at com.base.services.EmployeeServiceGrpc$EmployeeServiceBlockingStub.getBadgebyNumber(EmployeeServiceGrpc.java:373)
    at com.base.client.Client.sendMetaData(Client.java:66)
    at com.base.client.Client.main(Client.java:37)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9000
```

Comment: i didn't check everything but are you sure you have no firewall issue?

Comment: What is the code for the client? By the way ping may or may not work depending on firewall settings which may not allow ping requests to go through or the ping may not be operational. Depends on network settings and LAN stack settings.

Comment: Sorry guys, these where not the issues. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to `start()` your server, as [`build`](https://grpc.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/ServerBuilder.html#build--) suggests:

> Builds a server using the given parameters.
>   The returned service will not been started or be bound a port. You will need to start it with `Server.start()`.

Perhaps that `server.awaitTermination();` line could become

```
server.start().awaitTermination();
```

though I am not entirely sure.

Comment: Thanks @tevemadar. I missed that part.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same error. The reason being grpc server didn't start.

```
Server server = ServerBuilder.forPort(port).useTransportSecurity(certificate, key).addService(serverServiceDefinition)
            .build().start();
```

I had written start method as chain to build.
To make it work i had to call start() method separately.

```
server.start();
```

This solved the error for me.

*PS: I'm writing this answer as the above solution didn't clarify much and had to research alot before finding the solution. Hope this will be helpful for other developers.*